# Drag and Drop'ed file to input type file

Tags: php, html, file, uploading

I have a small problem that I cannot seem to find a solution for.
I have a simple form. It contains an input type file field, a select field, and a submit button. I would like to be able to drag and drop an image file in the input type file field without submitting the data directly to the script. So basically, i want the dragged'n'dropped file to act exactly like if i clicked on the Browse button and selected a file.

Comment: i tried several jQuery plugins, but they all seem to do the same thing: automatically upload the image when it's dropped. I don't want that, i just want the form to remain there till the user clicks on "Upload" submit button.

Comment: You want to use the HTML5 File API, not jQuery.  Read here - http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/

Comment: Take a look at http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/